# Need to open each login in the same browser window by reading mailids and passwords from a CSV file using Java in Selenium

Tags: java, csv, selenium, browser

I'm trying to read a CSV file containing Mail ids and Passwords using java in Selenium .After reading it, I need to login to each of these mail ids in the same browser. I have written the entire code for this, but the issue is that it is opening each userlogins in different browser windows. My requirement is to open each userlogins in the same browser window. I'm using Firefox browser.
Below is my entire code:
    package NewCsvPkg;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
//import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
//import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

//csv reader imports
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
//import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
public class NewCsvClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {

      //put this 4 lines inside while loop.

//         WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();   
//       String appUrl = "https://accounts.google.com";
//       driver.get(appUrl);
//       driver.manage().window().maximize(); 



     //csv reader aswathy -start
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("/home/user/Documents/UrmilaDocs/CSV PAck/testCSV.csv"));
        String [] nextLine;

        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext())!= null){

        String user_name = nextLine[0];
        String pass_word = nextLine[1];

        System.out.println("Username: " + user_name);
        System.out.println("Password: " + pass_word);


    //stackoverflow     
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
         String appUrl = "https://accounts.google.com";
         driver.get(appUrl);
         driver.manage().window().maximize();   


        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Email']"));
        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys(user_name);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='next']")).click();

        Thread.sleep(5000);
             //try
             try{
            WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']"));
              password.clear();
              password.sendKeys( pass_word);
              driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='signIn']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(8000);

        //click on 'Google Apps' icon 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gbwa']/div[1]/a")).click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        //Click on 'Gmail' icon to navigate to inbox page
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gb23']/span[1]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("Login Success");


        //Click on user name first letter circle icon
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/a/span")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        //click on 'Signout' button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gb_71']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("Logout Success");

        /*click on 'Signin with a different account ' option (since, after signing out from
//      the first user, he page is navigated to password entry page, which is supposed to navigate to 
//      username/mailid entry page  */
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account-chooser-link']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
//      /* In 'Choose an Account page', Click on 'Add Account' button */
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account-chooser-add-account']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
//          
    }catch(Exception e)
             {
                 System.out.println("Login failed!");  
             }// catch closed
//           //closing driver & firefox
             //driver.close();
             //System.exit(0);
            //end
        }   //while end

//      //closing driver & firefox
        // driver.close();
//     //csv reader aswathy -end
        System.exit(0);       //closing firefox  

  } 


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    You should initialise driver before entering into loop, currently you are initialising driver in loop thus causing driver to open multiple windows, also close firefox only after completing loop else you may face problem in next iteration of loop.

    Change it like this:

     //Initialise driver here and then go to loop:
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
             String appUrl = "https://accounts.google.com";
             driver.get(appUrl);
             driver.manage().window().maximize();   


     while ((nextLine = reader.readNext())!= null){

            String user_name = nextLine[0];
            String pass_word = nextLine[1];

            System.out.println("Username: " + user_name);
            System.out.println("Password: " + pass_word);


    }

   System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Its opening in same browser for first two logins.  But I have given 6 usernames and passwords in my CSV file. While executing , its not executing from the  third login onwards. Error is shown like this: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='Email']"}
Command duration or timeout: 17 milliseconds. Can you please correct me?